# How do you disable the autofocus of a webcam in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, webcam

I have a Logitech Pro 9000 webcam working with Mac OS X. I want to disable the autofocus feature of that webcam.

How to do this in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third Party drivers for web cams on the Mac include [Macam](http://webcam-osx.sourceforge.net/), [iUSBCam](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iusbcam/), and [iGlasses](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/iglasses/).

Comment: Throwing in a vote for iGlasses.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Kio Dane's answer is less helpful now for me, and I suspect it's since the Snow Leopard release.

- Macam hasn't been able to recognize
  any camera I've given it, even a well
  behaved "driverless" cameras.
- iUSBCam has a message on THEIR SITE saying
  that the program no longer works / no
  longer supported under Snow Leopard
  (that's why I suspect whatever change
  caused it also affects Maccam)
- iGlasses does work with my HP webcam
  on SL but doesn't have an option for
  auto-focus, even though the camera
  clearly has that feature. Also, it's
  $10, though might be worth it for
  other things.

This isn't anybody's "fault", I don't blame Kio or Apple, but things may have changed in SL.

If anybody has any ideas, please update. I'll check the vendor's site, HP in this case.